# What vulnerabilities have been found in Bitcoin Core using fuzzing?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, testing, fuzz-test

Is there a list of vulnerabilities that have been found in Bitcoin Core using fuzz testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a list of historical Bitcoin related CVEs (common vulnerabilities and exposures) see the [Bitcoin wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Common_Vulnerabilities_and_Exposures).

However, for a focus on Bitcoin Core vulnerabilities found by fuzzing there is a [resource](https://github.com/bitcoin-core/bitcoin-devwiki/wiki/Fuzz-Trophies) on the Bitcoin Core dev wiki on "fuzz trophies".

Marco Falke stated [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/21856#issuecomment-832438136) in May 2021:

> I did a survey of all bugs found first by fuzzing, excluding known
> bugs that can merely be reproduced by fuzzing (regression fuzz
> testing). I found that most bugs fall into one of the categories:
>
> - Silent merge conflict (forgetting to update the fuzz target after code changes)
> - A bug in the fuzz target itself
> - A recently introduced critical (exploitable) bug, but only present in    the master main development branch
> - A minor (non-exploitable) bug, potentially present in previous    releases